# svd code in recommender system error

Tags: c#, svd, csvde

I am using svd algorithm and I am using  coldstart form in suggestion system in my dataset(book crosing).

for leveraging sparsity with MathNet.Numeric befor using svD  in my form ,I am using This code in rating Table , But my code doesnt read a data set.

here is my code

```
var arrayOfDoubles = DenseMatrix.OfArray(To2D<double>
(dt1_rating.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] { 
 Convert.ToDouble(x[0]) }).ToArray()));
        //Select(x => new[] { Convert.ToDouble(x[0]), 
      Convert.ToDouble(x[1]) }).ToArray()));

        var S = arrayOfDoubles.Svd();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("USERID");
        dt.Columns.Add("ISBn");
        dt.Columns.Add("BOOKRATING");

        double[,] U = S.VT.ToArray();

        for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < S.VT.RowCount; outerIndex++)
        {


            for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < S.VT.ColumnCount; innerIndex++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["USERID"] = U[outerIndex, innerIndex];
                newRow["ISBN"] = U[outerIndex, innerIndex];
                newRow["BOOKRATING"] = U[outerIndex, innerIndex];
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

            }

        }
        dt1_rating = dt;///////////////////تا این جا
```

This is my error

Object cannot be Cast fromDbNull to other types 
or System Invalid CastExceptions

Comment: Don't understand what question you are asking.  A DataSet consists on one or more DataTables.  Most classes that require a DataSet will also accept one DataTable instead.  You can also add a DataTable to a DataSet if the class doesn't accept a single DataTable.

Comment: My data set is from book crossing , which is from table with rating and user and other items.
Now I want to use SVD for rating .
For the first I want to use svd and put it in to a data then use cold .what is your idea?

Comment: I added the error contex to the question.

Comment: Check if arrayOfDoubles, S, or U are null.  One or more of these 3 variables are null.

Comment: Thanks,it works.I have no error now.could you give an example of U matrix?  My result are same with cold state.

Comment: double[,] U = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

Comment: your numbers doesnt work.my SVD formula is data=U*S*VT.  I need real number for U matrix according to rating table.do have any suggestion?